# PHP data retrieval from database and display

Tags: php

How do I Limit some information displayed from the database and add a link eg "More" to enable read all information in a drop down using PHP. such as what is on facebook (Read more...). I am dealing with a lot of content and I dont want it all displayed at once. 
Here is part of the code

```
        echo    "<p>".$row['Firstname']."   ".$row['Lastname']."</p>";
        echo    "<p>".$row["Course"]." |  ".$row["RegID"]."</p>";
        echo    "<p>".$row["Email"]."</p>";
        echo    "<p>"."Tel:".$row["Telephone"]."</p>";
       echo     "<p>".$row["info"]."</p>";
```

The code is running well only that I want to limit the information

```
 
echo "<p>".$row["info"]."</p>";
```

so that not all is displayed
Thanks

Comment: use expander plug-in from jquery http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/demo/index.html

Comment: You probably want a Javascript solution for that. jQuery probably offers that functionality with one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#default) click on "view source" and you'll see it's very simple really, just set the row that you want as the header (what's clicked to show the rest) and store the rest in a div below.

Answer (score 0):

Split info into two strings, one intro, and the rest. Display only the intro to begin with. Insert a link that displays the rest when clicked.

```
$intro = substr($row['info'], 0, 200);
$rest = substr($row['info'], 200);

echo sprintf(
<<<HTML
<p>
   <span class="intro">%s</span><span class="rest" class="display: none">%s</span>
   <a href="" onclick="displayRest(this);return false;">Show more</a>
</p>
HTML
, htmlentities($intro)
, htmlentities($rest)
);
```

`displayRest` is a Javascript-function that, given a link, finds the previous span with class `rest`, shows it and removes the link. I leave it as an exercise to implement this in a way that fits your project. You can go with native Javascript, or use a library such as jQuery, YUI, MooTools, Prototype etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['more']))
{
    $query="select col1,col2,col3, ... ,colN from tableName ";
}
else
{
    $query="select col1,col2,col3 from tableName ";
}
```

//HTML

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="more" value="More" />
</form>
```

//PHP

```
$records=mysql_query($query);
   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($records))
{
 //Display 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The limit must be fixed on the SQL request.

```
// If you want to transmit limitation with a GET PARAMETER.
// You can also $_POST ur data.

$limitation = $_GET['limit']; 

//..... And in your SQL REQUEST

$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 0 , $limitation";

//And in the link....

echo '<a href="Your_Script_Page.php?limit=10">Show only 10 Results</a>'

?>
```

You can optimize that and add security precaution to prevent errors when $limitation receive empty or non numeric parameters.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['limit']) && !empty($_GET['limit']) && !preg_match(EXPRESSION, $_GET['limit'])){
//YOU CAN DO THE LIMITATION WHITOUT SQL ERRORS

}
else{
//ERROR DIRECTIVE
}
?>
```